# Google apps script cache in the library

Tags: caching, google-apps-script

I would like to write a script that is to be hosted in the Google Apps Resource Library that would cache data.  Obviously I would then want to access that cache with in other scripts from that library.

Is this possible and can anyone point in the right direction with some sample code?

Thanks,

Comment: are you sure you've got the right tags ? didn't you mean [google-apps-script] ? and could you clarify what you meant by 'cache date' ?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the Tag.  (New to stackoverflow, will be more thoughtful in the future)

Comment: --I meant data, not date.--  I have also looked at cookies and httpSession.  My ultimate goal is to get around the getUser outside you domain limitations from within a Google Apps Domain site.  I have users that have Google accounts, that are not on my domain whom I need to show specific information through GAS Ui hosted in a site.  I am just at a loss as to how to get this done.

Comment: please have a look at [Henrique's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050582/ownership-of-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thanks Serge, It seems the Henrique is unsure if his answer will apply to gmail accounts.  I did come across this: http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-cookies.html#more-91  I have put this into a library and applied the code with no errors returned.  I do get null on the return.  Should it work?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, since a library has a cache of it's own. You can see which resources belong to the library and which are shared in the [resource scoping](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries#scoping) section of the library user guide.